# MSOrleans 2.0 Ado.net Persistent

Tags: c#, .net

I am doing POC on MsOrleans and trying to save the grain in ado.net. But getting below error when launching Silo.

```
: Orleans.Runtime.SiloLifecycleSubject[100450]
      Lifecycle observer Orleans.Storage.AdoNetGrainStorage-OrleansStorage failed to start due to errors at stage 10000.
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Orleans.Storage.AdoNetGrainStorage.Init(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\build\agent\_work\23\s\src\AdoNet\Orleans.Persistence.AdoNet\Storage\Provider\AdoNetGrainStorage.cs:line 409
   at Orleans.Runtime.SiloLifecycleSubject.MonitoredObserver.OnStart(CancellationToken ct) in D:\build\agent\_work\23\s\src\Orleans.Runtime\Lifecycle\SiloLifecycleSubject.cs:line 75
fail: Orleans.Runtime.SiloLifecycleSubject[100450]
      Lifecycle start canceled due to errors at stage 10000
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Orleans.Storage.AdoNetGrainStorage.Init(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\build\agent\_work\23\s\src\AdoNet\Orleans.Persistence.AdoNet\Storage\Provider\AdoNetGrainStorage.cs:line 409
   at Orleans.Runtime.SiloLifecycleSubject.MonitoredObserver.OnStart(CancellationToken ct) in D:\build\agent\_work\23\s\src\Orleans.Runtime\Lifecycle\SiloLifecycleSubject.cs:line 75
   at Orleans.LifecycleSubject.WrapExecution(CancellationToken ct, Func`2 action) in D:\build\agent\_work\23\s\src\Orleans.Core\Lifecycle\LifecycleSubject.cs:line 115
   at Orleans.LifecycleSubject.OnStart(CancellationToken ct) in D:\build\agent\_work\23\s\src\Orleans.Core\Lifecycle\LifecycleSubject.cs:line 55
fail: Orleans.Runtime.Silo[100439]
      Exception during Silo.Start
Orleans.Runtime.OrleansLifecycleCanceledException: Lifecycle start canceled due to errors at stage 10000 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Orleans.Storage.AdoNetGrainStorage.Init(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\build\agent\_work\23\s\src\AdoNet\Orleans.Persistence.AdoNet\Storage\Provider\AdoNetGrainStorage.cs:line 409
   at Orleans.Runtime.SiloLifecycleSubject.MonitoredObserver.OnStart(CancellationToken ct) in D:\build\agent\_work\23\s\src\Orleans.Runtime\Lifecycle\SiloLifecycleSubject.cs:line 75
   at Orleans.LifecycleSubject.WrapExecution(CancellationToken ct, Func`2 action) in D:\build\agent\_work\23\s\src\Orleans.Core\Lifecycle\LifecycleSubject.cs:line 115
   at Orleans.LifecycleSubject.OnStart(CancellationToken ct) in D:\build\agent\_work\23\s\src\Orleans.Core\Lifecycle\LifecycleSubject.cs:line 55
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Orleans.LifecycleSubject.OnStart(CancellationToken ct) in D:\build\agent\_work\23\s\src\Orleans.Core\Lifecycle\LifecycleSubject.cs:line 63
   at Orleans.Runtime.Scheduler.AsyncClosureWorkItem.Execute() in D:\build\agent\_work\23\s\src\Orleans.Runtime\Scheduler\ClosureWorkItem.cs:line 63
   at Orleans.Runtime.Silo.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\build\agent\_work\23\s\src\Orleans.Runtime\Silo\Silo.cs:line 264
Orleans.Runtime.OrleansLifecycleCanceledException: Lifecycle start canceled due to errors at stage 10000 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Orleans.Storage.AdoNetGrainStorage.Init(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\build\agent\_work\23\s\src\AdoNet\Orleans.Persistence.AdoNet\Storage\Provider\AdoNetGrainStorage.cs:line 409
   at Orleans.Runtime.SiloLifecycleSubject.MonitoredObserver.OnStart(CancellationToken ct) in D:\build\agent\_work\23\s\src\Orleans.Runtime\Lifecycle\SiloLifecycleSubject.cs:line 75
   at Orleans.LifecycleSubject.WrapExecution(CancellationToken ct, Func`2 action) in D:\build\agent\_work\23\s\src\Orleans.Core\Lifecycle\LifecycleSubject.cs:line 115
   at Orleans.LifecycleSubject.OnStart(CancellationToken ct) in D:\build\agent\_work\23\s\src\Orleans.Core\Lifecycle\LifecycleSubject.cs:line 55
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Orleans.LifecycleSubject.OnStart(CancellationToken ct) in D:\build\agent\_work\23\s\src\Orleans.Core\Lifecycle\LifecycleSubject.cs:line 63
   at Orleans.Runtime.Scheduler.AsyncClosureWorkItem.Execute() in D:\build\agent\_work\23\s\src\Orleans.Runtime\Scheduler\ClosureWorkItem.cs:line 63
   at Orleans.Runtime.Silo.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\build\agent\_work\23\s\src\Orleans.Runtime\Silo\Silo.cs:line 264
```

Silo is working properly when I launch it without persistence.

Code Sample:

Silo adonet configuration:

```
        builder
         .AddAdoNetGrainStorage("OrleansStorage", options =>
          {
              options.Invariant = "System.Data.SqlClient";
              options.ConnectionString = orleansConfig.ConnectionString;          
          });
```

Grain Class:

```
    [StorageProvider(ProviderName = "OrleansStorage")]
    class CatalogGrain : Orleans.Grain<CatalogState>, ICatalogGrain
    {

 public async Task AddProductGrainToCatalog(IProductGrain productGrain)
        {

            State.Products.Add(productGrain);
            await base.WriteStateAsync(); 
        }
 }



public class CatalogState
    {
        public CatalogState()
        {
            Products = new List<IProductGrain>();
        }

        public string CatalogId { get; set; }

        public List<IProductGrain> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the error I could see that you have run the script to create the Table, but you missed the script to add data into it.
https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/blob/master/src/AdoNet/Orleans.Persistence.AdoNet/SQLServer-Persistence.sql
The documentation did mention that this is a common mistake by developers.
The documentation could be better by adding step by step how to instead of being so generic.

Anyway, run the script and let me know.